# Cakephp Data validation - This field cannot be left blank

Tags: cakephp

I'm using cakephp and I get a strange behavior with it.

Here is my validation rule in the Model:

```
    public $validate = array(
    'flyer' => array(
        'rule' => array('fileValidation', 'flyer', array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'), NULL, TRUE)
    )
    // Other rules...
);
```

Here is the fileValidation method (yes I'm french =) )

```
    public function fileValidation(array $check, $field, array $allowedMimeTypes = NULL, $maxFileSize = NULL, $allowEmpty = FALSE)
{
    $file = array_shift($check);
    $message = NULL;

    if($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
        //  checking uploaded file
        if(empty($file['tmp_name']) || empty($file['tmp_name']) || $file['tmp_name'] === 'none' || !is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'])){
            $message = "Une erreur est survenue lors de l'envoi du fichier, veuillez réessayer à nouveau. Si le problème persiste, merci de contacter le support technique.";
        }

        //  checking mimeTypes if required
        elseif(!empty($allowedMimeTypes) && !in_array($file['type'], $allowedMimeTypes)){
            $message = "Le type de fichier envoyé n'est pas celui attendu.";
        }

        //  checking file size if required
        elseif(!empty($maxFileSize) && $file['size'] > $maxFileSize){
            $message = "Le fichier envoyé est trop volumineux, réduisez sa taille et réessayez.";
        }

        else{
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    elseif($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE){
        // validates if no upload is allowed
        if(!$allowEmpty){
            $message = "Une erreur est survenue lors de l'envoi du fichier, veuillez réessayer à nouveau. Si le problème persiste, merci de contacter le support technique.";
        }
        else{
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    elseif($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE){
        $message = "Le fichier envoyé est trop volumineux, réduisez sa taille et réessayez.";
    }
    elseif($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE){
        $message = "Le fichier envoyé est trop volumineux, réduisez sa taille et réessayez.";
    }
    elseif($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL){
        $message = "Une erreur est survenue lors de l'envoi du fichier, le serveur n'a reçu qu'une partie du fichier, veuillez réessayer à nouveau.";
    }
    elseif($file['error'] >= UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR){
        $message = "Une erreur interne est survenue, veuillez réessayer à nouveau. Si le problème persiste, merci de contacter le support technique.";
    }

    // Here is the problem
    $this->validationErrors[$field][] = $message;

    return FALSE;
}
```

So far so good, my Validation rule seems to work correctly but when à get an error, I have two messages: "My custom message" and "This file cannot be left blank".

How to remove this message, where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you set the `allowEmpty` parameter of your rule to true?

Comment: Validation rule returns TRUE if no file has been uploaded, this is the equivalent to `allowEmpty` in cake which is not working on file input because there is an array. there is an error, i'm going to fix it (it actually returns TRUE whatever happen).
I Hope to be clear, sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cakephp.Saint's solution doesn't work because $message is a string, not an array but this works fine:

```
return $message;
```

Answer (score 2):

May be it will works for you

> ```
> $this->validationErrors[$field][] = $message; // comment this Line
> return FALSE // comment this Line
> ```
>
> And Add the following line at last of your fileValidation function
>
> **return implode("\n", $message);**